# Extract integer from a list

Tags: python

I have a list like `['-1', '1,2,3', '2']` and I want to extract all the integers in it.
I don't know the number of integers in each position of the list ie the list can also be `['2,3,4','1,2,3','-1']` but it will never have an empty string.
So I want that the answer should be `[2,3,4,1,2,3,-1]`

What is the best way to do so in terms of complexity as well as less code.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
map(int, ','.join(l).split(','))
```

where `l` is your list.

Comment: Hi @aix. I would like your opinion about if or when using map like that is better (faster, more flexible...) than going for a list comprehension. Ex: [int(x) for x in ','.join(l).split(',')] Or is it strictly equivalent? Cheers

Comment: @Morlock I think it's a matter of personal preference. I find `map(...)` slightly easier to read. I have't compared the two in terms of performance.

Comment: My understanding is that a list comprehension is faster than map in all but rare cases.  If you can express it as a list comprehension it's cleaner and more Pythonic.

Comment: So, from a 'purpose' point of view, both would be quite equivalent, right?

Comment: Out of curiosity just did a quick test, and `map` is about 20% faster on this code on my machine (Python 2.6.5). YMMV.

Comment: @Morlock Yes, functionally they're the same.

Comment: LOL, sorry. Faster. 20% faster.

Comment: Same here. :) map seems to work faster in this case, but keep in mind that when map() needs a lambda, a list comprehension is considerably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ist comprehension:

```
new_list = [ int(i) for i in ','.join(old_list).split(',') ]
```

Answer (score 0):

And another list comprehension.

```
>>> l = ['-1', '1,2,3', '2']
>>> [ int(x) for s in l for x in s.split(',')]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the same. Test gives the truth.
In THIS case, map() is faster than a list comprehension.

```
from time import clock
from random import randint

li = [ ', '.join([str(randint(-30,30)) for i in xrange(randint(1,8))])
       for j in xrange(1000) ]

A,B = [],[]

for fois in xrange(20):
    te = clock()
    res1 = map(int, ','.join(li).split(','))
    A.append( clock()-te )

    te = clock()
    new_list = [ int(i) for i in ','.join(li).split(',') ]
    B.append( clock()-te )

print '{:.1%}.'.format(min(B)/min(A))
```

a result: 115.1%.
not a big one, but there is a difference